# Running error without debugging on Monodevelop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I am using the monodevelop version 4.0.13-1 at Arch Linux.

When I try to run without debugging I get a error, and nothing appears at console output.
but if I go to the bin/ directory, it is possible to execute the builded code.

> Cannot execute "/path/to/project/bin/Debug/testes_console.exe". File ...

How can I run inside the monodevelop? This issue appears only when I am using console solution, with MVC and GTK this is not happening.

Comment: I've replaced the screenshot with text of the error message. Can you edit it to include the full error message?

Comment: i do not know how to show the full message... may you help me?

Comment: I don't have the software, but try moving your mouse over the message.